# Which version of Visual Studio best to develop .net 2

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have to develop a .net 2 asp.net website - which version of Visual Studio would people recommend using?

I'd prefer to develop using the client environment my clients insist on using - Windows XP 32 bit, IE6 to prevent any surprises when deploying.  The server running the asp.net site will be running on Windows 2003 under IIS6 and .net 2.0.

Comment: I Use VS 2013 without any issues

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend VS 2012, main reason is that VS 2010 (and lower) profiler doesn't work on Windows 8. And IMO profiler is important.

And also there are some new features in 2012 :

- Multiple browser support, ability to use any browser installed on system
- Support for HTML5 and CSS3
- better IntelliSense in the HTML and CSS editors
- better IntelliSense for JavaScript (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb385682.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You may use any version after Visual Studio 2005 which will resolve your issue.

Also many people recommend you to have the latest version of Visual Studio which is Visual Studio 2013 at present.

List of framework and Visual Studio is below:-

- 1.0: Visual Studio .NET
- 1.1: Visual Studio .NET 2003
- 2.0: Visual Studio 2005 / 2008
- 3.0 / 3.5: Visual Studio 2008
- 4.0: Visual Studio 2010
- 4.0/4.5: Visual Studio 2012
- 4.5, 4.5.1   Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Cheers Rahul - any particular reason why?

Comment: Why VS2010? This is a personal preference not an actual answer.

Comment: I knew that someone will surely ask. But I thats only my recommendation. Any version after Visual Studio 2005 will do the job for OP. :)

Comment: I don't know why anyone would willingly stick with 2010 specifically. It suffered all of the pain points of the transition to the new editors/WPF, etc, but doesn't benefit from the significant bedding in/performance improvements that have come in 2012 and 2013.

Comment: Well that was my recommendation only. However I have updated my answer as well as I thought that giving personal recommendation is not good. And I fully agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever!!! But since I have still not used VS2012 or later version so dont know their best features!! ;)

Comment: _Also many people recommend you to have the latest version of Visual Studio_ though I'm not sure 2013 is a good idea considering it's still in preview.

Answer (score 0):

Use VS 2013 Its pretty good .It has a drag and drop for designing sites like dreamweaver.  It's fast,  works in Windows 8 for making Metro UI apps, improved debugging